# Spring MVC Index Controller Strict Request

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller, indexing

Trying to map the index controller correctly.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ClientIndexController
{
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index()
    {
    }
}
```

or

```
@Controller
public class ClientIndexController
{
   @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
    }
}
```

These both approaches could not distinguish two different requests.

http://domain.com/

http://domain.com/?test=1 - in this case 404 must be thrown.

How can I avoid such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have Map with all request parameters, and check if the map is empty. Then you can implement a lot of different ways in creating a 404 (the one in the example below in only one way (maybe not the best)).

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ClientIndexController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams) {
        if(allRequestParams != null && !allRequestParams.isEmpty() {
            throw new ResouceNotFoundException();
        }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ResouceNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(404)
    public void RprocessValidationError(ResouceNotFoundException ex) {            
    }    
}
```

If you only want to check that a special parameter is not there then you could use

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params="!test")
public ModelAndView index(){...}
```